# Workflowy Chrome app says it's in offline mode

Tags: google-chrome

I use Workflowy, but am unsure if my issue is related to Workflowy or if it's a Chrome app thing. I've installed the Workflowy chrome app, and have it in its own window. I've been using it a while, however 8 days ago it started saying at the bottom of the window that it's offline (it now says that it's been offline for 8 days).

If I view Workflowy in Chrome itself via the URL (even on the same computer), then this shows the online synced version and doesn't include any changes that I've made in the Chrome app version over the past 8 days.

I don't really know how Chrome apps work for their internet access vs their webbased counterpart. Is there an offline mode that I might have accidentally enabled? I'm obviously concerned that I'll lose the unsynced changes I've made over the past 8 days.

I've emailed their support, but haven't yet had a reply.

Answer (score 1):

Their support got back today saying that it's a known issue. They did something to my account and it fixed it. So if you see this problem, then it looks like it needs to be fixed on their end.